# 403::Unknown Client Salesforce Workbench Push Topic

Tags: workbench, streaming-api, pushtopic

I have an object in Salesforce that I am trying to subscribe to using a Push Topic that I created. But when I try to subscribe to that push topic from Workbench I get `403::Unknown Client` exception.

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
{
  "advice": {
    "interval": 0,
    "reconnect": "handshake"
  },
  "channel": "/meta/connect",
  "id": "26",
  "error": "403::Unknown client",
  "successful": false,
  "action": "connect"
}
```

Comment: Without details of the object, query you are performing it would be difficult to suggest the cause. To narrow down further are you able to create a new simple Push Topic with the Query " SELECT Id, Name from Account ", and Subscribe to it?

This doc gives general details of 403 Unknown Client Error https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/streaming_handling_errors.htm

Comment: Its basically a custom object with 2 text fields for now. And yes, I've tried to subscribe to Account as well. I get the same error returned back.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are not using more than one CometD connection

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Workbench is an open-source free tool and is not officially supported by Salesforce. Streaming API subscription with Workbench is sometimes flaky and salesforce no longer recommends using Workbench. Can you use the EMP Connector, which is a Java client tool and also open-source: https://github.com/forcedotcom/EMP-Connector and see if the issue still persists.

Comment: Have you been able to check with EMP connector? Example here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/code_sample_java_client_intro.htm

Comment: Yeah, that worked just fine. Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for confirming Chashmeet. I will add my comment as an answer so others facing same issue will find the information helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workbench is an open-source free tool and is not officially supported by Salesforce. Streaming API subscription with Workbench is sometimes flaky and salesforce no longer recommends using Workbench. Please use the EMP Connector, which is a Java client tool and also open-source: [github.com/forcedotcom/EMP-Connector](https://github.com/forcedotcom/EMP-Connector) to fix the issue.

Example: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/code_sample_java_client_intro.htm