# Fail to subscribe platform event of a sandbox using workbench

Tags: platform-event

I failed to subscribe platform event of a sandbox using workbench. The error code is "403::Unknown client". "streaming api developer guide" says the error code means `The server deleted the client CometD session due to a timeout, which can be caused by a network failure. The client must perform a new handshake and reconnect.`

However, I can subscribe platform event of a product or developer org, under the same network, with the same browser environment.

I suppose sandbox org can't support platform event. Is it a known issue or how should I troubleshoot this?

```
Unknown exception occurred. Removing offending listener or subscription.
[
  {
    "advice": {
      "interval": 0,
      "reconnect": "handshake"
    },
    "channel": "/meta/subscribe",
    "id": "8",
    "error": "403::Unknown client",
    "successful": false
  },
  "Invalid argument: expected subscription, not undefined"
]
```

```
8. Subscription Failure: 403::Unknown client
{
  "advice": {
    "interval": 0,
    "reconnect": "handshake"
  },
  "channel": "/meta/subscribe",
  "id": "8",
  "error": "403::Unknown client",
  "successful": false
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the status shown in the Subscriptions related list on the Platform event? You might want to try recompiling trigger to see if it fixes the issue as mentioned in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/206577/sandbox-trigger-that-subscribes-to-platform-event-never-executes.

Comment: @Swetha I subscribed the platform event through the workbench client, not through trigger. Workbench threw the subscription failure: 403::Unknown Client. I don't see any record under Subscriptions related list on the Platform event.

Comment: Workbench is an open-source free tool and is not officially supported by Salesforce. Please use the EMP Connector, which is a Java client tool, and also open-source: github.com/forcedotcom/EMP-Connector and see of it fixes the issue.Related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/309049/403unknown-client-salesforce-workbench-push-topic/309926#309926