# Subscribing to platform event via workbench

Tags: platform-event, workbench

I'm trying to subscribe to a platform event in a Developer sandbox with the use of workbench (API 53.0). The use of Streaming API is enabled in setup.

Via the queries -> Streaming Push Topic -> Generic Subscription. Populating the subscription field with /event/eventName__e. When clicking the subscribe button I get the following error:

[image]

When doing the same in a production org I am able to subscribe with no issues. Is it the case you can only use the functionality in a production org?

If so what is the best way to subscribe to a platform event via a sandbox?

As a side note I was trying this via workbench to provide examples of what a received message would look like.

Comment: Duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/314432/fail-to-subscribe-platform-event-of-a-sandbox-using-workbench

Comment: If you just need to provide examples of what a received message would like (since, workbench doesn't seem to be working for sandboxes), you could explore an alternate option of using [Streaming Monitor](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FYEEWUA5) (available in app exchange, developed by [@POZ](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/31996/poz)). Seems to be as easy to use app with better UX